# grep in all directories

Tags: grep, subdirectory

I have a directory named XYZ which has directories ABC, DEF, GHI inside it. I want to search for a pattern 'writeText' in all *.c in all directories (i.e XYZ, XYZ/ABC, XYZ/DEF and XYZ/GHI)
What grep command can I use?

Also if I want to search only in XYZ, XYZ/ABC, XYZ/GHI and not XYZ/DEF, what grep command can I use?

Thank you!

Comment: The `--recursive` and `--include`/`--exclude` flags are probably what you want

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
grep -R --include="*.c" --exclude-dir={DEF} writeFile /path/to/XYZ
```

- `-R` means recursive, so it will go into subdirectories of the directory you're grepping through
- `--include="*.c"` means "look for files ending in `.c`"
- `--exclude-dir={DEF}` means "exclude directories named `DEF`. If you want to exclude multiple directories, do this: `--exclude-dir={DEF,GBA,XYZ}`
- `writeFile` is the pattern you're grepping for
- `/path/to/XYZ` is the path to the directory you want to grep through.

Note that these flags apply to GNU `grep`, might be different if you're using BSD/SysV/AIX `grep`. If you're using Linux/GNU grep utils you should be fine.

Comment: Great explanation of each argument!

Comment: If there is another directory like XYZ/CCC/DEF,  does this command exclude this directory also? but I only want to exclude XYZ/DEF. @wkl

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following command to answer at least the first part of your question.

```
find . -name *.c | xargs grep "writeText"
```

Comment: getting this message:
find . -name *.c | xargs grep "writeText"
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [path...] [expression]

Comment: I works in my Ubuntu machine. Can you try using just find . -name *.c, and share the result.

Comment: Same message. My system is redhat.

Comment: Can you check by putting the name of the current folder explicitly in place of dot.